# mule datamapper - first line of the csv file has been skipped

Tags: csv, mule, datamapper

Data mapper has skipped the first line of the csv file during processing. How do i include the first line of the file in payload?

Appreciate your reply at your earliest convenience.

Thanks.

Comment: Mind including what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Open your mapping file: mapping/yourmapping.grf, click on the settings(cog) icon at the top left hand side and set 'Rows to ignore' to 0.